# Trying to connect 2 Dell 2015H monitors one with VGA and one with VGA to DVI connector on my ThinkPad pro dock

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I have a lenovo x240 laptop connected to a ThinkPad Pro dock.  The dock has a VGA and a DVI connector.  I have 2 dell 2015H Screens with VGA connections.  I purchased a VGA-DVI converter to plug one screen into the VGA port on the dock and another through the DVI port on the dock.  The monitor plugged in with VGA is working.  The monitor I have connected with the VGA to DVI-D converter to the DVI port on the dock isn't being recognized by my Intell 4400 card.  Everything I've looked at online seems that this connection should work, but no dice.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm running a windows 7 64-bit OS, and Intel 440 graphics card.  Other specs let me know.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the Thinkpad supports two different monitors?  Last time I used a Thinkpad w/ dock it would support only one monitor and the laptop screen...NOT two different external monitors.  The plugs you may be seeing might be to handle a single monitor with EITHER a DVI or VGA connector.

Comment: To be honest I did use this setup at my old company and am trying to replicated it at home with my new equipment.  So prior I had a lenovo thinkpad that I could use 2 external monitors plus my laptop screen if needed.  My changes this time are the Dell screens are not the same.